# duplicate class found in android(Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

Application description:
I have an app called TODO. In this application, I first have a custom list in which there is a tick option, a Title and a Description. And it can be seen on the MainActivity page. There is also a FAB to add ToDo, Title and Description. This application is connected to ROOM and DataBase.

What are the problems of the program?:
When running the application, the following error that can be displayed on GitHub is displayed. What is the reason?:
https://gist.github.com/amoozeshbebin/418cd2a436862b530e2d3a2f4c609c2c#file-error

Application codes:
https://gist.github.com/amoozeshbebin/15d0e117f3f65a58097d22121a9e7263

[image: error image:]

Answer (score 0):

you are using mutiple libraries that are used for similar function try any one from the following:
(com.intellij:annotations:12.0)
(org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)

Comment: I used this code like this, is it correct?:
implementation("org.jetbrains:annotations:12.0")
That didn't work, but instead I put Dependendys for you:

Comment: https://gist.github.com/amoozeshbebin/c02f20b0de3e2f96cdc7bd3de89793c3#file-dependendys-kt

Comment: implementation ("org.jetbrains:annotations:12.0")
 implementation ("org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0")
use any one version

Comment: i use this but didn't work please say another way

Comment: THE PROBLEM IS implementation ("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0") AND WHEN I DELETE THIS APP FIX BUT CRASH BECAUSE CAN'T RUN APP WITHOUT THIS IMPLEMENTATION

Comment: I DON NOW WHAT I NEED TO DO TO FIX IT PLEASE HELP ME THANKS

Comment: remove any one lib from above

Comment: i do that but app need lib